# How to .get_else with with a pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas pd.Series.get method has a default parameter (much like dict.get) that suggests I should be able to use it lookup an item in its index and returns the row's value, but return the default when the query is not in the index.

Indeed it works (and is equivalent to .loc where default=NAN):

```
# x10

maptable = pd.Series(      [100, 110, 120, 130],
                     index=[10,  11,  12,  13]).sort_index()

query_vals = pd.Series([11,12,15], index=['A', 'B', 'C'])

# Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
print maptable.get(query_vals, float("nan"))
11    110.0
12    120.0
15      NaN

# Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
print maptable.loc[query_vals]
```

... but complains that "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative."

Isn't the purpose of .get (over .loc) exactly to allow lookup with missing indexes.

What am I supposed to do here to avoid this warning? I'm not sure how .reindex helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#reindexing) can be passed a array-like `index` of labels.
If the label is in the index, the value is returned. If it isn't, then (by default) `NaN` is returned:

```
In [17]: maptable.reindex(query_vals)
Out[17]: 
11    110.0
12    120.0
15      NaN
dtype: float64

In [18]: maptable.reindex(query_vals, fill_value='foo')
Out[18]: 
11    110
12    120
15    foo
dtype: object
```

The FutureWarning:

> FutureWarning: 
>   Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
>   KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
>
> See the documentation here:
>   https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike

is recommending you use `.reindex` instead of `.get` or `.loc`.

Comment: Thanks -- that seems to be it. Is odd -- how can .get(..., default=d) every return d without every raising the warning? It seems identical to .reindex except that .reindex raises a warning. Without the default parameter, it seems identical to .loc.

Comment: [`Series.get`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L2474) relies on `__getitem__` indexing (i.e. using `self[key]`).
The `FutureWarning` applies to passing "list-likes to ... `[]` with a missing label",
so `Series.get` is essentially deprecated in favor of `reindex`. Note however that `.get` is a generic NDFrame method. `DataFrame.get` currently still works without warning. I'm not sure if that might change in the future though.

Comment: [This github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15747) explains the reason for the change, and [this pull request](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/20770) implements it.